# Python 2.7 - Take two JSON's and combine the string field values together and add int fields

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, bigdata

I am trying to take two JSON's that are composed of a mix of integers and strings and combine them together using python 2.7.

for example:

```
{"key": {"field_string": ["string"],"field_num": 1}}
{"key": {"field_string": ["another_string"],"field_num": 2}}
```

The requirements of what I am trying to do are:

- The key's will be the same and will need to remain the same after the merge
- The integers need to be added together, so 1 + 2 = 3, and the strings will need to be added together in an array format (they are already in an array like above).
- A range of fields per JSON, most JSON's will have between 4-7 fields

An example of what I would want the output to look like, based on the above:

```
{"key": {"field_string": ["string","another_string"],"field_num": 3}}
```

Also, the project I am using this for will be on a machine with no access to the internet, so I need this to work with the standard python libraries if possible.

Any assistance with this would be appreciated. Most of the examples I am finding involve combining the two JSON objects together, however, the integers don't get added, a key part that I need to happen.

**UPDATE**

for a little more background into this, this is a project I am working on that I can't go into much detail behind, however, I can give a pseudo code example.

The basic idea behind what I am doing is, I have a lot of JSON's I need to combine. In the example, I have simply listed it as two, however in the final version of my code it will process thousands of JSON's (big data project). The JSON portion of it is just a small part of what I am trying to accomplish but a critical part.

here is a example-ish of how one of the JSON's is structured:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "blue_data": 12,
    "green_data": 0,
    "red_data": [],
    "yellow_Data": [
      "string_1",
      "string_2",
      "string_3"
    ],
    "foo": "XX",
    "bar": "YYY",
    "foobar": "ZZZZ"
  }
}
```

However some fields may be omitted, example the last 3 fields may or may not be included, or a subset of them.

The way the JSON objects are passed to my script is in the form of an array. So the array will hold a series of JSON's that I was iterating over using a for loop.

```
for key in list_of_keys:
    for item in json_list:
        json_dump_data = json.loads(item)
        try:
            json_blue_data[key]
        except:
            json_blue_data[key] = int(json_dump_data["blue_data"])
        else:
            json_data_data[key] = json_blue_day[key] + int(json_dump_data["blue_data"])
```

I was doing something similar to the above for each value, I would basically break each field down into a dict object and combine them at the end. I know it's not the most effective way to do this however, I am new and working with pre-existing code.

Comment: convert JSON to Python object (dictionary), do what you need and convert Python Object (dictionary) to JSON - use `JSON` standard module.

Comment: please provide an example that demonstrate the `A range of fields per JSON, most JSON's will have between 4-7 fields` requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming that all keys will have the same value type.

It allows depth up to about 1000 (the default Python max stack depth)

```
import json

obj1 = json.loads('{"key": {"field_string": ["string"],"field_num": 1}}')
obj2 = json.loads('{"key": {"field_string": ["another_string"],"field_num": 2}}')

def combine(obj1, obj2):
    for k, v in obj1.items():
        if k in obj2:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                combine(obj1[k], obj2[k])
            else:
                # assume list or int based on problem description
                obj1[k] = obj1[k] + obj2[k]


combine(obj1, obj2)
print json.dumps(obj1)
```

Output:

```
{"key": {"field_string": ["string", "another_string"], "field_num": 3}}
```

Comment: `list + list` also works so this could be simplified, check for dict and recurse else `obj1[k] += obj2[k]`.

Comment: great suggestion. added.

Comment: NP. BTW `x += y` is more efficient than `x = x + y` - for lists as the former does an in place update to `x` vs creating a 3rd list and then assigning it to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert JSON to Python object (dictionary), do what you need and convert Python Object (dictionary) to JSON again. Use JSON standard module.

```
import json

# input JSON
json1 = '{"key": {"field_string": ["string"],"field_num": 1}}'
json2 = '{"key": {"field_string": ["another_string"],"field_num": 2}}'

# convert JSON to Python dictionary
dict1 = json.loads(json1)
dict2 = json.loads(json2)

# create dictionary for results
dict3 = {'key': {}}

# do what you need
dict3['key']['field_string'] = dict1['key']['field_string'] + dict2['key']['field_string']
dict3['key']['field_num'] = dict1['key']['field_num'] + dict2['key']['field_num']

# convert result to JSON
json3 = json.dumps(dict3)

print(json3)

# {"key": {"field_num": 3, "field_string": ["string", "another_string"]}}
```